# Google apps script "TypeError: data.getCell is not a function", cant find where im wrong

Tags: google-apps-script

im creating code for autofilling callendar, but as you can see i cant figure out how to use .isBlank properly, if you have any question please ask

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl ('my link');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("new project")
  var v1 = sheet.getLastRow()
  Logger.log(v1);
  var v2 = sheet.getLastColumn()
  Logger.log(v2);
  var data = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  Logger.log(data);
  for (var i = 1; i < v1; ++i) 
  {
    n=i+1
    Logger.log(i);
    var data1 = sheet.getRange(n,1,1,13).getValues()
    Logger.log(data1); 
    var cell = data.getCell(n, 9); //error in this row
    if (cell.isBlank()) 
    {
    Logger.log(cell); 
    }
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your snippet, `data` comes from [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues), which doesn't return a [range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range), so you cannot use [getCell()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getcellrow,-column).

Since you already have the values in an array (`data`), you can access them directly without using [getCell()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getcellrow,-column): `var cell = data[n][9];`. For the same reason, you won't be able to use [isBlank()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isblank), so you might want to use something like `if (cell === "") {}`.

---

Edit:
As mentioned in the comments of this answer, `n` was not defined, so you might just want to use `i` instead, so it'd become `var cell = data[i][9];`:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('my link');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("new project")
  var v1 = sheet.getLastRow()
  Logger.log(v1);
  var v2 = sheet.getLastColumn()
  Logger.log(v2);
  var data = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  Logger.log(data);
  for (var i = 1; i < v1; ++i) {
    //Logger.log(i);
    //var data1 = sheet.getRange(n, 1, 1, 13).getValues()
    //Logger.log(data1);
    var cell = data[i][9]; 
    if (cell === "") {
      Logger.log('blank cell');
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, it was very informative but i have another problem, " TypeError: Cannot read property '9' of undefined

Comment: Is there any reason for you to use `n` (which doesn't seem to be declared, by the way) instead of `i`? And to use `v1` instead of `data.length`?

Comment: i change n to i and i=2 now, and isnt data.length will be the same as v1?

Comment: Yes, it should be the same, and that's why I'm asking why you need to use both. In any case, it's not very clear what you're trying to with that snippet. You mention a calendar, but the snippet just checks if cells of column 9 are blank.

Comment: just to comfirm my size with logger, tho problem is that this sniped is a thing that i want to use, because in some cases there is nothing in a row starting from cell 9, and for some reason i cant do it properly, it just says: TypeError: Cannot read property '9' of undefined

Comment: I've updated the answer with a sample code that doesn't use `n`. I've tested it, and it's working as long as you have 8 columns or more.

Comment: thanks for helping, and sorry for invconveniece, but i still have same issue, its not problem in n, its in: var cell = data[i][9];  this row and error is: TypeError: Cannot read property '9' of undefined, i cant even start to understand how why or where to begin with it

Comment: Based on that error, you need to check why `data[i]` is undefined. Without accessing your data, I cannot know the reason. You can publish it (https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965) so it's easier to find out the problem. In any case. the code in my answer worked fine in my tests, so you might want to double-check your code and the data it uses.

Comment: so, interesting, i know the reason, but i dont know how to deal with it, for some reason, when i take values from sheet it also "takes" whole row of empties, looks like this: [, , , , , , , , , , , , ] and i dont know how to fix it, and actualy error is after everything else is correctly done, have any ideas?

Comment: Even if it takes empty rows, as long as the index `i` is smaller than the number of retrieved rows, that error shouldn't happen because `data[i]` would be able to access a valid subarray (even if it's empty).

Comment: me stupid, error in a third row, for some reason error in trird(final row) and for some reason first row that have 9 column with writed info is shows like a blank, i tried to see whats in cell during during whole program but for some reason its null, so basicaly cell dont exctract specific cell from data, mb i made data wrong? also mb the problem that i dont use latin letters in sheet? but i dont think it is a problem

Comment: You can use "non-latin" characters without any problems.

Comment: huh, then its data? but why it displays correctly then? when i defined it i checked if its correct and in logger it is, except extra emty row for some bizzare reason, to be honnest im just lost mb should i try to create anoter question with this specific thing?

Answer (score 0):

[getCell(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getcellrow,-column) returns a given cell within a range.
"data" is not range, it is an array.
If you want to refer to the range from which the array of "data" values was obtained, correct line:

```
var data = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()
```

to 2 lines:

```
var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()
var data = range.getValues();
```

and `var cell = data.getCell(n, 9)` to `var cell = range.getCell(n, 9)`